# How do I get a list of documents from subcollections that contain a specific document id?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get a list of documents from the "members" subcollections that contain a specific document id?

result should be doc id 'HPqr6X5flVC2DSugfb3A' if "members" collection contain child doc 'tu50FK1uXxfeTmzdJFkBdg0q1b82'

Checkout the [image: database screenshot].

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? From the screenshot, what are you trying to get?

Comment: put more light to your question

Comment: this my 1st question please click on the image link

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to get the list of documents from a collection group (a set of collections with the same id) and compare the document id with the id you're querying with using [FieldPath.documentId](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath/documentId.html).

Here's a sample:

```dart
var id = 'f8ed8ddd-7e3d-4cdc-bc63-1fe5de5ef8e7';
var querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collectionGroup("members")
  .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: id)
  .get();
var documentList = querySnapshot.docs;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but still error. I need to get doc id in "wecare_group" where doc id in "members" contain specific document id.

result should be doc id 'HPqr6X5flVC2DSugfb3A' if in "members" contain doc id 'tu50FK1uXxfeTmzdJFkBdg0q1b82'

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/unknown] An error occurred while parsing query arguments, see native logs for more information. Please report this issue.
E/flutter (26596): #0      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:108:7)
E/flutter (26596): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26596): #1      _JsonQuery.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart:389:9)
E/flutter (26596): <asynchronous suspension>